# equivalent to titeInhibit for Cygwin's rxvt-native?

Tags: cygwin, less, rxvt

Some programs, such as less, have the annoying idea that I should not be allowed to keep loking at the content of a file while I'm typing the next command. They save the contents of the terminal when they start and then blank out all their own output when they exit.

In an xterm, this can be suppressed by setting a `*titeInhibit` X resource, or at runtime using ctrl-Mouse3. However, cygwin's rxvt-native does not react to ctrl-Mouse3, nor (naturally) does it read X resources.

Is there a way to get rxvt-native to refuse to do the ti-te/smcup-rmcup/alternate screen madness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want LESS to clear the screen when it finishes, just use `less -X` . You can make this happen by default by setting the LESS environment variable. `export LESS=-X` .

Comment: Yes, but I'd like a solution that I won't have to repeat each time I ssh into a different server (with a shared administrative account where I'm not supposed to start customizing the profile).

Comment: According to [man ssh](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ssh+1) you can put `LESS=-X` in the file ~/.ssh/environment and ssh will set that environment variable for you (if you have export permissions).

Comment: That's an interesting idea.